# How can I start ServerManager.msc on a 64bit Windows Server 2008 from a 32bit .NET App?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, 64-bit, wow64

I have the following scenario:
- 64bit Windows Server 2008.
- 32bit .NET application (needs to be x86 for various reasons).
- I need to start ServerManager.msc from my .NET application.

When using Process.Start("ServerManager.msc"), I get the following exception:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.
Message="The system cannot find the file specified".

On a 32bit Windows Server 2008 the code works fine...
I tried to inlcude the full path to ServerManager.msc, but that does not help either.
Also no difference if running with or without admin privileges.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On WOW64, if a 32-bit application refers to C:\Windows\System32; the operating system transparently remaps this to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (which is where the 32-bit stuff lives).

As a 32-bit application on Win64, you need to specify the full path as `%SYSTEMROOT%\SysNative\ServerManager.msc`.

`SysNative` doesn't exist on x86 Windows (there's no reverse mapping, at least on Win7 Ultimate), so you'll need to figure out whether you're on x86 or x64 first.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp! This helped me solve the issue. As a final step, I also needed to replace "ServerManager.msc" by "CompMgmtLauncher.exe", because the .msc file was indirectly loaded by mmc.exe. I now open the file like this: Win32Api.GetWindowsDirectory() + "\SysNative\CompMgmtLauncher.exe"

Answer (score -1):

Please use [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out which file/dll is missing.

If it is using an x86 native dll/library which is compiled in newer version of VC++ Runtime. Install the latest VC++ runtime on the 2008 server. Latest I believe is [2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en).

Comment: Not relevant to Process.Start